# C# performance of static string[] contains() (slooooow) vs. == operator

Tags: c#

Just a quick query:
I had a piece of code which compared a string against a long list of values, e.g.

```
if(str == "string1" || str == "string2" || str == "string3" || str == "string4".
     DoSomething();
```

And the interest of code clarity and maintainability I changed it to

```
public static string[] strValues = { "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4"};
...
if(strValues.Contains(str)
    DoSomething();
```

Only to find the code execution time went from 2.5secs to 6.8secs (executed ca. 200,000 times).
I certainly understand a slight performance trade off, but 300%?
Anyway I could define the static strings differently to enhance performance?
Cheers.

Comment: Is this part of the code the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: @mark, does it matter? the question is about getting more performance,  which is a good question in its own right.

Comment: "a long list of values": How long is "long"? How many strings do you have in your list?

Comment: About 12 values. The "long2" part really wasn't important, just the performance difference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Fyi..

Using:

```
private static HashSet<string> strHashSet = new HashSet<string>() 
{ "0string", "1string", "2string", "3string", "4string", "5string", 
  "6string", "7string", "8string", "9string", "Astring", "Bstring" };

private static List<string> strList = strHashSet.ToList();
private static string[] strArray = strList.ToArray();
private static Dictionary<int, string> strHashDict = strHashSet.ToDictionary(h => h.GetHashCode());
private static Dictionary<string, string> strDict = strHashSet.ToDictionary(h => h);

// Only one test uses this method.
private static bool ExistsInList(string str)
{
  return strHashDict.ContainsKey(str.GetHashCode());
}
```

Checking for the first and last strings in the list then checking for a string not in the list: "xstring"
Executing 500,000 iterations, all times in milliseconds.

```
1.A Test: result = (str == "0string" || str == "1string" ...
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strArray                 3.78 :  45.90 :  57.77 :  35.82

2.A Test: ExistsInList(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
none                    36.14 :  28.97 :  24.02 :  29.71

3.A Test: .ContainsKey(string.GetHashCode());
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashDict             34.86 :  28.41 :  21.46 :  28.24

4.A Test: .ContainsKey(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strDict                 38.99 :  32.34 :  22.75 :  31.36

5.A Test: .Contains(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashSet              39.54 :  34.78 :  24.17 :  32.83
strList                 23.36 : 122.07 : 127.38 :  90.94
strArray               350.34 : 426.29 : 426.05 : 400.90

6.A Test: .Any(p => p == string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashSet              75.70 : 331.38 : 339.40 : 248.82
strList                 72.51 : 305.00 : 319.29 : 232.26
strArray                38.49 : 213.63 : 227.13 : 159.75
```

Interesting (if not unexpected) results when we change the strings in the list:

```
private static HashSet<string> strHashSet = new HashSet<string>() 
{ "string00", "string01", "string02", "string03", "string04", "string05", 
  "string06", "string07", "string08", "string09", "string10", "string11" };
```

*With "string99" as the none check.*

```
1.B Test: result = (str == "string00" || str == "string01" ...
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strArray                85.45 :  87.06 :  91.82 :  88.11

2.B Test: ExistsInList(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
none                    30.12 :  27.97 :  21.36 :  26.48

3.B Test: .ContainsKey(string.GetHashCode());
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashDict             32.51 :  28.00 :  20.83 :  27.11

4.B Test: .ContainsKey(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strDict                 36.45 :  32.13 :  22.39 :  30.32

5.B Test: .Contains(string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashSet              37.29 :  34.33 :  23.56 :  31.73
strList                 23.34 : 147.75 : 153.04 : 108.04
strArray               349.62 : 460.19 : 459.99 : 423.26

6.B Test: .Any(p => p == string);
[storage var]          [first]:[ last ]:[ none ]:[average]
strHashSet              76.26 : 355.09 : 361.31 : 264.22
strList                 70.20 : 332.33 : 341.79 : 248.11
strArray                37.23 : 234.70 : 251.81 : 174.58
```

For cases A and B looks like tests 2 and 3 have the advantage.

However, HashSet.Contains(string) is very efficient, not effected by list contents and has a clear syntax...might be the best choice.

Yes, it is true, I have no life.

Answer (score 5):

Both the methods you have tried have O(n) performance so they will get slower as you add more strings. If you are using .NET 3.5 or newer then you could try using a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead and initializing it once at the start of the application. You can then get approximately O(1) lookups.

For .NET v2.0 you can emulate a `HashSet` using a `Dictionary<string, object>` and using `ContainsKey` and not using the value.

Comment: Sorry but you're little bit wrong. I think the best for Framework 1.x is `System.Collections.Hashtable`. Because 1.x has no generics!

Comment: @abatishchev: You're right that 1.x has no generics. But I feel it's OK to assume people aren't using .NET 1.x these days unless they mention it in their question. Having said that, I've reworded my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: just did a experiment, and HashSet is the same speed as the ifs.

Comment: @Keith Nicholas: Sorry, what `ifs` is? Ah.. A number of `if`.. :)

Comment: @ab,   multiple if conditions :)  plural of if :)

Comment: @Keith Nicholas: Have you tried ~1000 ifs for ~1000 times? :)

Comment: I did 4 conditions in an if statement 200000 times.   vs string[] vs HashSet.

Comment: @Keith: HashSet is faster for large n. 4 is not a very large value of n.

Comment: @mark  exactly, and yet is just as fast at just 4 :)  so it only gets better for bigger n

Comment: @abatishchev: The original question is in C# 3 / .NET 3.5: the Contains method is an extension method (there is no public Contains method on the Array class). So using a `HashSet<T>` should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Are you actually running this 200,000 times in production code? You may want to consider hash checks as a faster negative-check if so.

If the 200,000 times was just to illustrate the difference, then I wouldn't worry about it. It's only a *0.02 millisecond* increase in time.

`Contains` is more general-purpose than testing static strings, so there is a small amount of overhead. Unless this code is a bottleneck as Mark mentioned, it's not worth optimizing. There's a famous quote in CS: "premature optimization is the root of all evil." The quote isn't quite accurate, but it's a good reminder of the ultimate optimization guideline: *measure first*.

Comment: thats all well and good,  but you shouldn't be wasteful when its just as easy to use a more efficient alternative.  and replacing string[] with HashSet is more efficient, and just as concise.  That way efficient mechanisms are chosen by default,  whether they actually make a real difference or not

Comment: I find that *clear and readable code* is a much greater timesaver than pouring a lot of work into micro-optimizations that have undetectably-small runtime impact when used in real-world scenarios.

Comment: sure...  but as I said, if there are more efficient defaults that are of equivalent readability that you can choose, you should.    the advice of premature optimization was mainly given in the context of structuring systems in favor of performance that may never pay off.  Problem is, people now use it as an excuse not to be generally efficient when they can.  the replacement of string[] with hashset causes no structural change

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative you may arguably find readable and maintainable, that you may wish to test for speed. If you do test it for speed, please post your result!

```
        switch (str)
        {
            case "String1":
            case "String2":
            case "String3":
            case "String4":
                DoSomething();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: As far as I could remember, C# compiler automatically creates some kind of a hashtable for switch-case block if count of cases is more then 4.

Comment: you'll need a `break` after `DoSomething()` for that to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Although using a `HashSet<string>` as suggested could be a better option, the reason why `strValues.Contains(str)` is slower, is because it's a generic extension method. There is no such thing as a Contains method on arrays.

The way it works for arrays is basically

```
if (strValues is ICollection<string>) // true
{
    return ((ICollection<string>) strValues).Contains(str);
}
```

which adds a typecheck, typecast and virtual call. Then it will iterate the array (causing bounds checks). Only then will it come to do string comparisons. So it's doing a *lot* more work.

Note that in C# 3 (which you must be using if you're using extension methods), you can simply initialize the `HashSet<string>` like this:

```
public static HashSet<string> strValues = new HashSet<string> { 
                                   "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4" };
```

This keeps your program just as readable as it is now using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that Contains() works better for a longer list. It may, for example, sort the list and do a binary search (just a thought experiment, for an example.)

Comment: Unfortunately, Contains cannot make such assumptions. It will always do a linear search on arrays.